# Mysql Server Table Encryption Not working

Tags: mysql

I have been following the MySQL table encryption reference manual, I have installed the keyring plugin, created table with encryption and then inserted the data into it. When I do a select on the table I do see the raw data.

I have run the following query to validate my result

```
SELECT PLUGIN_NAME, PLUGIN_STATUS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PLUGINS WHERE PLUGIN_NAME LIKE 'keyring%';
```

Result of the above query

```
Plugin_Name         Plugin_Staus
Keyring_file        Active
```

Another Query

```
select @@keyring_file_data;
```

Result

```
var/lib/mysql-keyring/keyring
```

Also gave permission to all the users to this folder

Created table  with Encryption

```
create table t1(c1 int,c2 varchar(10)) ENCRYPTION='Y';
```

Insert data

```
Insert into t1(c1,c2)values(1'Test');
```

Also to verify that tables are encrypted I did run the below query

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, CREATE_OPTIONS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
     WHERE CREATE_OPTIONS LIKE '%ENCRYPTION="Y"%';
```

The reference manual followed is at the location https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-tablespace-encryption.html